# How to create business profile in Magento 2.3.2 community edition

Tags: magento2, customer-account, magento-community

How to create business profile in Magento 2.3.2 community edition. I need to add one more account other than customer account in the top links.

Comment: Can you please provide more information? are you talking about different customer types?

Comment: yes..we have introduced business profile user.

Comment: Would it not be simple enough to just add a customer group via the admin

Comment: please suggest me any plugin available for this?